# Activities for different companies in one workplace

Tags: coworking

There are two diffrent companies in 1 workplace. The one is marketing company. The other is a team of designers. As an office manager I should create some kind of activity to attract people from two companies (this activity should help them to get to know each other)
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean to say these are 2 **different companies** ? or do you mean to say these are 2 **different departments** from the same company ?

Comment: Do you have buy-in (that means a boss agreeing to it) from *both* companies? Are they both okay with their employees unavailable for work while you have an "activity"? Who asked you to do this? What is your position, who does an "office manager" of two companies work for?

Comment: Do you work as an office manager for 1 of these 2 companies ?

Comment: Why do you feel that you can't just leave people alone to get on with their work?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Designers and marketing people party very differently. The different fields attract different personalities which enjoy very different things and different activities. Junior members of both teams dislike how the other team operates and dislike the culture of the other. For them to mingle, they have to respect what the other provides.

Comment: "Any ideas -- brainstorming -- is sorta out of scope here. I will say that when out building managers hosted events they tended to be food-based -- a large BBQ dinner for all the tenants on the adjacent lawn/park, or cookies/ice cream in the lobby, recognizing that done with want to socialize, some will just want to eat, sone will be interested in games ("giant jenga" seemed popular) and some will grab food and go right back to their desks... and all of those are reasonable responses. You can't mandate participation, though getting buy-in from manglement helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

> should I create some kind of activity to attract people from two companies ?

1. **During The Business Hours:**

   If these are 2 different **companies** and you work for 1 company,
   then the answer is **NO**. Please don't do that **during the
   business hours** as it may interfere with their jobs.
2. **Outside Business Hours:**

   It may be OK to ask if people from both companies would
   like to socialize or to have a drink at a local bar or restaurant
   together either during lunch or  **after work** on Friday. Some
   people may like the idea, and some don't because they may want to socialize with a few people on their teams. But, you can ask politely.